# What are those Wooden Tube thing?

Tags: bleach, culture

In Episode 32 when Renji is going through the story of how he and Rukia met and became Soul Reapers, at the start when we see what his life was like in Rukongi District 78 - Hanging Dog, the Old Man that he and his Friends steal from had these tubes which appeared to carry liquid which seemed to spill out when he fell onto his table.

My first guess would be these are some form of water bottle used in Feudal Japan so i am looking for confirmation if these tube things are. if not what are they? and do they have a basis in Japan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes their purpose is to store water or a different liquid.
I've seen them in other anime and manga but I cannot remember them though.
 In general they've been used all around Asia.
This one for example is from Borneo and it can be seen that it is heavily decorated:
[image]

Here is the [Shop](http://borneoartifact.com/modules/product/?show=info&id=3348) were it is available more information.

It has current day versions like these:

[image]

[link](http://tomocchi.hamazo.tv/e5804304.html)

[image]

[link](http://tomocchi.hamazo.tv/e5804304.html)
[image]

[link](https://minne.com/items/3385426)

They are usually handmade, being made in the wild when hiking or camping [like this](https://sensiblesurvival.org/2013/03/08/make-a-bamboo-canteen/).

This is all the information I could gather including some japanese websites (I have no knowdeledge of the Japanese language). I found information only on shopping websites and I hope it is not against the rules. I hope it is a conclusive answer even if it has ambiguous sources.

Comment: wow that bamboo in the last picture can be used as stabbing weapon. hmmm, that give me idea